# Why "less than" doesn't work when "equal' works?

Tags: verilog, logical-operators

I have a simple project:

```
NET "sw<2>"   LOC = "P89";
NET "sw<1>"   LOC = "P95";
NET "sw<0>"   LOC = "P101";
NET "ld"   LOC = "P59";
```

```
module top_module(
    input [2:0] sw,
    output ld
);
assign ld = sw == 3'd2;
endmodule
```

It compiles without any erros. However, if I change the `==` to `<`, it won't:

> WARNING:PhysDesignRules:367 - The signal <sw<0>_IBUF> is incomplete. The signal does not drive any load pins in the design.
>
> WARNING:Par:288 - The signal sw<0>_IBUF has no load.  PAR will not attempt to route this signal.

Can anyone explain me why is that happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the only two (unsigned, integer) numbers less than 2 are 1 and 0, so the bottom bit of the number doesn't matter, i.e. sw[0] doesn't matter.  There's nothing 'not working' here, just some probably-irrelevant warnings.

The warnings are just telling you that sw[0] doesn't affect the output.  If you change the comparison to `<=`, then the warnings will go away, because the logic will need to care about sw[0] again.